# Queue Ble Android send only on time

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth-lowenergy

I worked on a Ble peripheral, I used a queue from this [article](https://www.toothpasteandbubblegum.com/blog/queued-data-bluetooth-le-android) to send data, but it works only one time.

I received a request from Central after a successful connection with the value "0301" then in the same characterstic I set the data (ssid) and I notify it, so right now everything works fine,  and the app (peropheral) stop receiving request.

```
@Override
        public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(final BluetoothDevice device, final int requestId, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, final int offset, final byte[] value) {
            super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);
            final String hexValue = byteArrayToHexString(value);
            // 0x83, 0x01, 0x41, 0x62, 0x63
            final byte[] ssid  = new byte[]{(byte)  0x83, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0x63};
            final byte[] pwd  = new byte[]{(byte)  0x01, (byte) 0x02};
              BluetoothGattCharacteristic charact = mBluetoothGattServer.getService(serviceUUID).getCharacteristic(characteristicUUID);


            if(hexValue.equalsIgnoreCase("0301"))
                writeQueue.add(ssid);
            if(hexValue.equalsIgnoreCase("0401"))
                writeQueue.add(pwd);

            if (isWriting) {
                return;
            }
            if (writeQueue.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            isWriting = true;
            charact.setValue(writeQueue.poll());

            boolean result =  mBluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, charact , false);
          

    if (responseNeeded) {
            boolean sendResponse =  mBluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device,
                    requestId,
                    BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS,
                    0,
                    null);
            
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says: "An application must call BluetoothGattServer#sendResponse to complete the request."

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback#onCharacteristicWriteRequest(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20byte[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback#onCharacteristicWriteRequest(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20byte%5B%5D))

Comment: thank's I remove this part while posting the code I tought it's not important, I edit my code, can you see now ?

Comment: removing  if (isWriting) {
                return;
            }
and if (writeQueue.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }
the code worked like a charm